# Terraform: Assign a role to the service account of a newly created google cloud build trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I've just created a new Google Cloud Trigger using Terraform and it fails because of missing permissions when running the deploy step (it's missing `role/cloudfunctions.developer`)

I know I can add the role to the service account using something like:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "act_as" {
  project = var.google_project
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member  = "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID_HERE@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

but I think it would be more robust if I could just reference the service_account used by the google_cloudbuild_trigger resource, something like:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "act_as" {
  project = var.google_project
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_cloudbuild_trigger.my-trigger.service_account}"
}
```

This fails with:

> ╷
> │ Error: invalid value for member (IAM members must have one of the values outlined here: > https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy#Binding)
> │
> │   with module.pipedrive.google_project_iam_member.cloudfunctions-developer,
> │   on modules/pipedrive/main.tf line 66, in resource "google_project_iam_member" > "cloudfunctions-developer":
> │   66:   member  = google_cloudbuild_trigger.build-trigger.service_account

I think it's because the format of the `service_account` attribute is not what's expected in the member input.

Any hints? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the value of `${google_cloudbuild_trigger.my-trigger.service_account}`?

Comment: Um.. I'm not sure how to print variable values inside a module.

Comment: Try `terraform state show`. Example in the docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/show#example-show-a-module-resource

Comment: ```
running: terraform state show 'module.pipedrive.google_cloudbuild_trigger.build-trigger' | grep "service_account"

returns nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the service account's details separately because `google_project_iam_member` needs the SA's email. `google_cloudbuild_trigger` only holds the service account's ID, as you pointed out.

Use the `google_service_account` module to load the service account's details, including its email, and then pass that to `google_project_iam_member`. See this [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger#example-usage---cloudbuild-trigger-service-account):

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "service-account-trigger" {
  trigger_template {
    branch_name = "main"
    repo_name   = "my-repo"
  }

  service_account = google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.id
  filename        = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.act_as,
    google_project_iam_member.logs_writer
  ]
}

resource "google_service_account" "cloudbuild_service_account" {
  account_id = "cloud-sa"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "act_as" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.email}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand correctly, you're creating a NEW service account (named 'cloud-sa'). I'm not sure if I want to do this.

Comment: @runixo you can import existing resources into your terraform state: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import

Comment: @runixo You can also just use the `google_service_account` data source to reference the existing SA: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/service_account

Answer (score 0):

So, I *think* I understand what's happening.
In the [Google Cloud Build Triggers API docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers#:%7E:text=then%20the%20standard%20Cloud%20Build%20service%20account%20(%5BPROJECT_NUM%5D%40system.gserviceaccount.com)%20will%20be%20used%20instead.%20Format%3A), it's stated that if no service_account is specified then the Google Cloud Build default service account is used:

The service account used for all user-controlled operations including triggers.patch, triggers.run, builds.create, and builds.cancel. If no service account is set, then the standard Cloud Build service account ([PROJECT_NUM]@system.gserviceaccount.com) will be used instead. Format: projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_ID_OR_EMAIL}

I was expecting the API to return the default service_account (but it's not, it's returning 'null').

So I ended up doing a coalesce between `google_cloudbuild_trigger.build-trigger.service_account` and the default Cloud Build service account.

```
data "google_project" "project" {
  project_id = var.google_project
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "cloudfunctions-developer" {
  project = var.google_project
  role    = "roles/cloudfunctions.developer"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${coalesce(google_cloudbuild_trigger.build-trigger.service_account, "${data.google_project.project.number}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com")}" #TODO FIXME
}
```

I hope this helps others, I learned a few things investigating this.
Thanks for your help!